# Configuring maven for proxy

Tags: maven, proxy, maven-plugin

I'm new to maven build tool, but I'm not able to configure maven for proxy server.

In the `/usr/share/maven/settings.xml` 
I added the following lines:

```
  <proxies>
  <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.foo.bar.com (http://proxy.foo.bar.com/)</host>
      <port>911</port>
    </proxy>
    <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>https</protocol>
      <host>proxy.foo.bar.com (https://proxy.foo.bar.com/)</host>
      <port>911</port>
    </proxy>
 <proxy>
</proxies>
```

But when I do mvn package.
I get the errors:

```
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.3/maven-resources-plugin-2.3.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.245s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Dec 27 10:10:30 PST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/87M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.3: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.3 from/to Central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)): IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 29: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.3/maven-resources-plugin-2.3.pom -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: remove the `(http://proxy.foo.bar.com/)` string and try

Comment: @AbhinavSarkar: nope.. not working :(

Comment: Please post your whole settings.xml file.  It appears that you may not have the correct entries for maven central.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The host for a proxy entry should not contain parenthesis.

It should look like.

```
  <host>proxy.foo.bar.com</host>
```

You can see in the first part of your console output that parenthesis are getting added to your path.

```
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.3/
```

It should look like

```
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.3/
```

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrectly configured the path to the Maven central repository just as you have incorrectly configured the path to your proxy.  The entries should look just like standard urls and not contain any parenthesis.